# iOS Row Selected not being called

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Ive added a print statement in my row selected method and it is never being called:

```
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Row selected");
    }
```

My cells have a `UIImageView` that covers the whole cell acting as a background image. Could this be causing the row to not recognize the touch?

Comment: You should be setting the image as the background view. Otherwise it will cover the cell.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Cant the background view be a uiimage? Or do I need to cast it?

Comment: An image view is a subclass of view. You shouldn't need to cast it.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I've changed it to the background view but the row selected is still not being called.

Comment: Does it work without the image view?

Comment: Then that's not the problem here. Did you make sure to wire up the table views delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to call:

```
MyTableView.AllowsSelection = true;
```

It must have been set to `false` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Adding latest: Visual Studio/Xamarin iOS/C#

1) Add IUITableViewDelegate to the ViewController.cs

2) On ViewDidLoad:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            this.yourTableview.Delegate = this;
            this.yourTableview.AllowsSelection = true;
        }
```

3) Implement IUITableViewDelegate the method.

```
[Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
public virtual void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row Selected");
}
```

Please note that RowSelected will not be called if [Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")] is not added.